# speedtest-cli does not execute when scheduled cron

Tags: networking, server, bash, 20.04, cron

Server: **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS**

Command: **speedtest** | **speedtest-cli**

I have a bash script to identity download & upload speed every **15 mins**.
When i execute it manually it works well but not on cron.

1st time, Suppose at 12:00 it executes properly and following is the output

> Testing from AT&T Services (12.26.3.241)...
>
> Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
>
> Selecting best server based on ping...
>
> Hosted by AWI networks (St. George, UT)
>
> Testing download
> speed.........................................................................
>
> Download: *** Mbit/s
>
> Testing upload
> speed......................................................................
>
> Upload: *** Mbit/s

2nd time, 12:15 :-

> Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
>
> Testing from AT&T Services (12.26.3.241)...
>
> Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
>
> Selecting best server based on ping...

And when I check user's mail, Following is the error :-

> ERROR: Unable to connect to servers to test latency.

Comment: any question? how to help with no view on the script and no view on the cron task ?

Answer (score 5):

Same Problem here.
It seams link the Server is overloaded at specific times.
My cron-expression is
`"0 /15 * 1/1 * ? *"`
so the Job started:
10:00, 10:15, 10:30 ...

I changed the cron-expression to
`"0 4/15 * 1/1 * ? *"`
so the job starts:
10:04, 10:19, 10:34 ...

Solved the problem for me.

Kind Regards

Comment: Started facing the same problem. Queries at 00 minutes would fail. Changed to a different minute within the hour and it worked!

Comment: Jobs at 0 and 30 failed repeatedly, but offsetting the jobs with some minutes delay solved the issue for me. `--timeout` has no effect, error `ERROR: Unable to connect to servers to test latency.` occurs within seconds.

Comment: same here. broke at `*/30 * * * *` but worked fine when I offset the time. i'm guessing there is a latency spike to the speedtest.net servers at even 1/2h because everyone using automated scripts will poll at the exact same time.

Answer (score 0):

The classic reason for cron jobs not working when the same job works on the command line is that the environment is different. You can fix that with the following:

1. Place the commands you want to run in a script not forgetting to add the shebang.
2. Add a source command before the commands you want to run so that your .bashrc configuration is loaded.
3. Make sure your script is executable.
4. Adjust cron to run the script using the full path to the script.

```
    source /path/to/your/.bashrc
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try adding following flags to your .sh script, it solved problem for me:

My script *run_speedtest.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
speedtest --accept-license --accept-gdpr >> /home/xxx/speedtesty/results
```

Crontab entry:

```
/10 * * * * /bin/bash /home/xxx/speedtesty/run_speedtest.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this - if you put a script in cron you need to not use "" to encase the command you want to run.  The script works on the command line like this, but not in cron.  Use '' to encase the command instead as follows (I use the csv option so I can do something with the results):

I create a variable called `SPEEDTEST` to run the command as follows, then run it using `$SPEEDTEST`

`SPEEDTEST='/usr/local/bin/speedtest --csv'`