# Crontab shellscript is not using the gui theme properly

Tags: scripts, cron

I have a script that checks the Calibre website daily for updates, and notifies when a new version is available.
The crontab entry for it is like this:

```
0   12 * * * DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus /home/sadi/.local/share/bin/cron-daily-jobs.zsh 2> /home/sadi/.local/share/cron-user.log 2>&1
```

Everything works fine, except the appearance of the dialog box, which seem to ignore my current theme (except window decoration). I suspect I'm missing something in that part before the script path name to make the script use my theme.

The screenshot shows the dialog box from crontab (top), and what it should look like normally (bottom).
[image]

Comment: My answer to another cron question may solve this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322451/speedtest-cli-does-not-execute-when-scheduled-cron/1322504#1322504

Comment: @PonJar Thanks, but unfortunately adding it to crontab entry (just before the actual script to run) prevented it from running at all. I wish crontab were less complicated. ;-)

Comment: I think the source command needs to be in the script you run, not in the crontab. Cron can be a pain. If you are not aware of them, research systemd timers. They are usually less problematic than cron and can do the same sort of things

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Thanks, but I would appreciate so much if you could also tell me which environment variables I need to include in that wrapper script? Probably more than just $USER and $HOME I guess... BTW, I also have SHELL=/bin/zsh at the top of my crontab entries.

Comment: To find which environment variables a particular executable (`less` in this example) makes use of do this: `strings $( type -p less) | grep -E '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*$'`.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved this problem by switching from **crontab** to **systemd service timer**, which seems better suited for scripts with GUI elements.

For the record, I'd like to summarize how I did it:

1. Create directory and configuration file for user systemd services:

   `mkdir "/etc/systemd/user@.service.d"`

   `sudo touch "/etc/systemd/user@.service.d/local.conf"`
2. Copy and paste the following into this file:

> ```
> [Service]
> Environment="PATH=/usr/lib/ccache/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
> Environment="EDITOR=nano -c"
> Environment="BROWSER=firefox"
> Environment="NO_AT_BRIDGE=1"
> ```

3. Create directory and get data for user environment setup:

   `mkdir "~/.config/environment.d"`

   `systemctl --user show-environment > "~/.config/environment.d/user.conf"`
4. Create directory for systemd user files:

   `mkdir "~/.config/systemd/user"`
5. Create a service file (e.g. "`test.service`") and corresponding timer file (e.g. "`test.timer`") for each job:

Sample service file contents:

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=Perform systemd service timer test
>
> [Service]
> ExecStart=~/.local/bin/test
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=default.target
> ```

Sample service file contents:

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=Run test service every 10 minutes
>
> [Timer]
> OnCalendar=*:0/10:0
> Persistent=false
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=default.target
> ```

6. Enable the newly created service and timer:

   `systemctl --user enable test.timer`